# How to use single.php for creating, reading and editing Custom Posts with ACF

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, advanced-custom-fields, single

I have a WordPress custom post type **product** and I am now developing front end forms for creating, reading and editing these posts (I am using ACF).

I am trying to use only **single-product.php** for this purpose! Can someone help me on this regard?

I already achieved to view *(host/product/theproduct)* and edit a post *(host/product/theproduct?action=edit)* basically by adding *?action=edit* on the links and showing specific **acf_form()** if the **$_GET["action"]** is **edit** but I also want to use this page for **creating new posts**!

I tried to add ***new_product*** on URL like ***host/product/new_product*** and check on backend for that (and then show the create new product form) but because there is no *new_product* post it is redirecting to 404 page :(

I have no idea how to achieve this for the moment so any help/suggestion would be very appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd probably need to create a separate *page* with the same form on it for new products.

Answer (score 1):

The context isn't *really* right for creating a new post.  You'll be on single-product.php if you're viewing an existing post, but not for a post that you've yet to create!

I can think of two approaches.

1 - put an "Add Product" link or button onto your existing form and configure it so that a new product is created and you are redirected to that product so that you can now fill in your existing edit form to complete the data entry.  I guess this kind of mirrors what the WP Admin does.

2 - just have a page template (or custom template with a custom URL rewrite) with the New Product form on, replicating pretty much what you already have in your edit form.

Hard to give some helpful code with no code in your question but hopefully these pointers will help.

Comment: I now that this request its kind of weird but it will help me a lot (not making many files)